# Can a Website block it's content for a selenium bot?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Good evening,

I am currently working on a selenium Bot, that Posts some of my articles on the Platform Ebay-Kleinanzeigen, but somehow I cannot access the Login page with my Bot.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class Ebaybot:
    def __init__(self, username, pw):
        self.driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r'C:\Users\dsbh0\Desktop\Ebaybot\msedgedriver.exe')
        self.driver.get("https://www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de")
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/button[1]").click()
        sleep(5)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/section[1]/section/nav/ul/li[3]/a")\
            .click()
        sleep(5)
        # self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div/div/input")\
        #     .click()
        # sleep(2)
        # login_field = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[1]/div/div/input")\
        #     .send_keys(username)
        # self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/div/input")\
        #     .click()
        # pw_field = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div[2]/div/div/input")\
        #     .send_keys(pw)



my_bot = Ebaybot("User","pw")
```

I already tried to use Chromedrive and I've had the same issue with it.

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cX9BD.png)

Comment: Yes websites can block automated web clients, including Selenium. Selenium does nothing to hide itself and is particularly easy to detect. Websites typically use fingerprinting solutions to determine the authenticity of web clients.

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to scrape Ebay, so keep in mind a large site like Ebay likely uses modern antibot technologies to mitigate scalpers, avoid Ad Fraud, and etc.

Comment: Maybe answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/70133896#70133896.